# hamburger not shown in menu collapsed using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 with the standard css shipped with the package.
I have built a menu out of the basic structure provided in the examples and built this HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                  <!--<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>-->
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo_small.png" alt="Montglane"></a>
              </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="active voce"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="movimenti">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Movimenti <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="banca.php">Banca</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="carta.php">Carta di credito</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="timesheet.php">Timesheet</a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>-->
                                    <!--
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    -->
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="report">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Report <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="report_banca.php">Banca</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="report_carta.php">Carta di credito</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="geco.php">Geco</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="fattura.php">Fatture</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="anagrafiche">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Anagrafiche <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="banche.php">Banche</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="carte.php">Carte</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="clienti.php">Clienti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="commesse.php">Commesse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="movimenti.php">Tipi Movimenti</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li></li>
                  </ul> -->
                  <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a href="login/loggedin.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome_est']; ?></a></p>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
</nav>
```

It works but when it comes to small viewports it stopped showing the hamburger. I have inspected the code and the menu options are there to be shown but I miss the three lines button to toggle menu visibility. What kind of mistake did I do?
Note that I didn't apply any custom css or js by now.

Comment: You commented the HTML section of the button. See line 4 to 10. Button including 3 spans `icon-bar`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the comments ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now as answer ;)

You commented the HTML section of the button. See line 4 to 10. Button including 3 spans icon-bar.

Comment: Thanks. I'll flag it as soon as I can do it (SO says I have to wait 10 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

you have commented hamburger menu section

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo_small.png" alt="Montglane"></a>
              </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="active voce"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="movimenti">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Movimenti <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="banca.php">Banca</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="carta.php">Carta di credito</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="timesheet.php">Timesheet</a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>-->
                                    <!--
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    -->
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="report">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Report <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="report_banca.php">Banca</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="report_carta.php">Carta di credito</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="geco.php">Geco</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="fattura.php">Fatture</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown voce" id="anagrafiche">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Anagrafiche <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="banche.php">Banche</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="carte.php">Carte</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="clienti.php">Clienti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="commesse.php">Commesse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="movimenti.php">Tipi Movimenti</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li></li>
                  </ul> -->
                  <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a href="login/loggedin.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome_est']; ?></a></p>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
</nav>
```